# PyCharm does not detect all versions in requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, fastapi, requirements.txt

Currently, my `requirements.txt` in my project looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see, PyCharm can detect the version and everything for `uvicorn`, but not for `fastapi`.

How can I change that?